# Can mongoDB split read and write, with primary on HDD, replica sets on SSD?

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have three machines, each machine both has SSH and HDD, I want to save SSD space, and in my env: less write, lots read. So does mongoDB support splitting read and write, with primary on HDD, replica sets on SSD. If so, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send **rs.stepDown(300)** to the replicas on the SSD disks that you want as Secondary. Then they won't get chosen for the next 5 minutes. The replica on the HDD should be Primary when all the others step down.

Also make sure that you can read from your secondaries with **rs.slaveOK()**.

In case that your primary has problems, one of your secondaries will take over. *(Unless if you really don't want that, you can use {priority:0} in the member options.)* Be aware that your script with these tasks, should only execute when your 'previous primary' is synced correctly again, before you return to your preferred environment. This could be automated as a cronjob or sometimes better manually if you need to figure out what happened with the Primary.

To optimize read/write:

- [Howto Benchmark and test limits](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104835/mongo-is-using-5-7-of-cpu-so-why-is-my-computer-so-slow/104836#104836)
- [Split different database files by task : journal/log/data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104530/good-ratio-for-data-journal-and-log-drive-sizes-for-mongodb/104535#104535)

Comment: Thank you @aldwinaldwin, I have another question, if I put primary and another replica set node (for voted to be a primary, if original primary down) on ssd, other replica set nodes on HDD, Is this a better way?

Comment: If I use sharding, will there be anything wrong with this scene?

Comment: Sharding is just having multiple "replica sets". So for each shard you can do the same.  About how many need to be on SSD or HDD, that's a matter of opinion/preferences/needs. But you do great in thinking well about your system and options. You might want to write some benchmarking and testing scripts to create different scenarios. Mostly I write some python test scripts that I let run and observe what happens if I bring down the primary, and when you fix your preferred state. And even if you want/need to go further, put logfiles and journal directory away from datadisk...

Comment: Thank you @aldwinaldwin,  would you please share your python test scripts to me? If possible, please tell me your code address(github?) or send to my email: zwb.ict@gmail.com. Thank you vey much!

Comment: @zwb : added the simple speed test on the Howto Benchmark and test limits link